# Wrong hibernate column type: Found: undefined

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I get the following exception on server (websphere) startup. `VIEW_LTABLE_FULL_CLEARANCE_DAY` is a view on Oracle

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Wrong column type in CALMS2CMS_SCHEMA_25.VIEW_LTABLE_FULL_CLEARANCE_DAY for column table_code. Found: undefined, expected: varchar2(255 char)
        at org.hibernate.mapping.Table.validateColumns(Table.java:373)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validateSchema(Configuration.java:1305)
        at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator.validate(SchemaValidator.java:155)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:512)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1797)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:96)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:914)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:899)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateEjbPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateEjbPersistenceProvider.java:51)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:360)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:384)
        ... 41 more
```

The TABLE_CODE column definition is :

```
TABLE_CODE  NOT NULL VARCHAR2(5 CHAR)
```

The Hibernate entity mapping of that column is:

```java
@Column(name = "table_code")
private String tableCode;
```

View definition:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW VIEW_LTABLE_FULL_CLEARANCE_DAY (
  TABLE_TYPE,
  TABLE_CODE,
  TABLE_TERRITORY_CODE,
  DESCRIPTION,
  FULL_CLEARANCE_DAYS,
  RECEIPT_REQUIRED
) AS
SELECT
   TYPE AS TABLE_TYPE,
   CODE AS TABLE_CODE,
   TERRITORY_CODE AS TABLE_TERRITORY_CODE,
   DESCRIPTION,
   FULL_CLEARANCE_DAYS,
   RECEIPT_REQUIRED
FROM PAYMENT
```

What I do not understand is why the error says `Found: undefined`.

The mapping seems correct.

Comment: Why used force view? Do your view created normally? try without it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the error goes away when I re-create the views. 
But I still don't know why I kept getting the initial error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try to correct your `tableCode` definition in the following way:

```java
@Column(name = "table_code", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR2(5 CHAR)")
private String tableCode;
```

as suggested in [this](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-fix-wrong-column-type-encountered-schema-validation-errors-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) article.

Comment: I could but I dont want it to be oracle specific. Regardless, it doesn't explain why the  error says "undefined"

Comment: @Navs please add to the question information about hibernate version and hibernate dialect that you use.

Comment: Hibernate version 4.2.13.Final

Comment: @Navs and hibernate dialect

Comment: @Navs and oracle version

Comment: DB : Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: Dialect: Oracle10gDialect